# Stack Pointer does not load at the startup in ARM Cortex M4 (Tiva C Series TM4C123GH6PM)

Tags: gcc, arm, cortex-m, bare-metal

I'm trying to write the most simple program for Tiva C launchpad. Stack pointer value and program counter value are automaticaly taken from the two first 32-bits words of flash. But, for somehow reason, when I debug with gdb, the stack pointer gets 0x0. This causes that program fails. I'm using this instructions to debug:

```
(gdb) target extended-remote :3333
(gdb) monitor reset halt
(gdb) load
(gdb) monitor reset init
```

Program in assembly is startup.s:

```
        .syntax unified

        .section .vector_interrupt, "x"

    g_pfnVectors:
        .word 0x20007FFF
        .word _Reset

        .text
    .global _Reset
    _Reset:
        mov   r0, #0
        b stop

    stop:   
        add   r0, r0, #1
        b stop
```

the linker file Tiva.lds:

```
ENTRY(_Reset)

MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00040000
    SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00008000
}

SECTIONS {
        .vector_interrupt : {
        KEEP(*(.vector_interrupt));
    } > FLASH

    .text : {
        . = 0x0000026c;
        * (.text);
    } > FLASH

}
```

and the makefile:

```
gcc=arm-none-eabi-gcc
objcopy=arm-none-eabi-objcopy

FLAGS= -ggdb3 -nostdlib -std=c99 -mcpu=cortex-m4 \
       -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Wall \
       -Werror -nostartfiles

csum.bin: csum.elf
    $(objcopy) -O binary csum.elf csum.bin

csum.elf: startup.s
    $(gcc) $(FLAGS) -T Tiva.lds -o csum.elf \
    startup.s

openocd:
    openocd -f ../openOCD/ek-tm4c123gxl.cfg
```

What is wrong?

**Actualization**

I was trying to avoid put the exception handlers. However, Now I put them. The problem is that i'm getting an UsageFault at startup.

I did this modifications: 
startup.s:

```
.syntax unified

        .section .vector_interrupt, "x"
g_pfnVectors:
        .word   _stack_start
        .word   _Reset
        .word   NMI           /* NMI Handler */
        .word   HardFault     /* Hard Fault Handler */
        .word   MemManage     /* MPU Fault Handler */
        .word   BusFault      /* Bus Fault Handler */
        .word   UsageFault    /* Usage Fault Handler */
        .word   0             /* Reserved */
        .word   0             /* Reserved */
        .word   0             /* Reserved */
        .word   0             /* Reserved */
        .word   SVC           /* SVCall Handler */
        .word   DebugMon      /* Debug Monitor Handler */
        .word   0             /* Reserved */
        .word   PendSV        /* PendSV Handler */
        .word   SysTick       /* SysTick Handler */

        .text
.global _Reset
_Reset:
        mov   r0, #0
        b stop

stop:   
        add   r0, r0, #1
        b stop               @ Infinite loop to stop execution



        .align  1
        .thumb_func
        .weak   Default_Handler
        .type   Default_Handler, %function
Default_Handler:
        b   .

/* Macro to define default handlers */
        .macro  def_handler handler_name
            .weak   \handler_name
            .set    \handler_name, Default_Handler
        .endm

        def_handler NMI
        def_handler HardFault
        def_handler MemManage
        def_handler BusFault
        def_handler UsageFault
        def_handler SVC
        def_handler DebugMon
        def_handler PendSV
        def_handler SysTick
        def_handler DEF_IRQHandler
```

Tiva.lds:

```
ENTRY(_Reset)

MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00040000
    SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00008000
}

_stack_start = ORIGIN(SRAM)+LENGTH(SRAM);

SECTIONS {
        .text : {
            KEEP(*(.vector_interrupt));
            * (.text);
        } > FLASH

}
```

This is the output from arm-none-eabi-objdump -d csum.elf

```
csum.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <g_pfnVectors>:
   0:   20008000    .word   0x20008000
   4:   00000040    .word   0x00000040
   8:   0000004d    .word   0x0000004d
   c:   0000004d    .word   0x0000004d
  10:   0000004d    .word   0x0000004d
  14:   0000004d    .word   0x0000004d
  18:   0000004d    .word   0x0000004d
    ...
  2c:   0000004d    .word   0x0000004d
  30:   0000004d    .word   0x0000004d
  34:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
  38:   0000004d    .word   0x0000004d
  3c:   0000004d    .word   0x0000004d

00000040 <_Reset>:
  40:   f04f 0000   mov.w   r0, #0
  44:   e7ff        b.n 46 <stop>

00000046 <stop>:
  46:   f100 0001   add.w   r0, r0, #1
  4a:   e7fc        b.n 46 <stop>

0000004c <BusFault>:
  4c:   f7ff bff8   b.w 4c <BusFault>
```

The reasons for the UsageFault can be:

- An undefined instruction

– An illegal unaligned access

– Invalid state on instruction execution

– An error on exception return

but i don't figure out what is the reason.

Comment: What are the first 8 bytes of the generated binary?

Comment: I wonder if the problem is because the second entry in the vector table is not the reset handler when it should be (_Reset is at 0x0000026C whereas the vector table entry is 0x0000026A). That

Comment: You should be able to say `.word _Reset` and let the linker fix up the correct address. And I think the vector should be an odd number (because it's a Thumb entry point)? [However, "all flash memory with zeros" sounds like the more serious problem!]

Comment: Your .bin has nothing in it. I would expect it to look similar (identical) to the .elf.

Comment: By the way, a base 16 dump would be equally expressive and much more compact than base 2 :)

Comment: Did you first try running the available boot up code from TI to compare?

Comment: so it actually boots with a 0x40 instead of 0x41 in the reset vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing in ARM assembly is tricky. There were three problems with this code.

1. The `.vector_interrupt` section did not make it to the binary file because it did not have the ALLOC attribute. `objcopy` ignores sections without the ALLOC attribute. As a result, the initial stack pointer and reset vector were zeroes. To fix this, the section attributes should read "xa":

   ```
   .section .vector_interrupt, "xa"
   ```
2. Another problem: initial stack pointer is unaligned. Change it to:

   ```
   .word 0x20008000
   ```

This is assuming the MCU has at least 32KB RAM.

3. Branch target addresses should have the LSB bit set to one to indicate Thumb mode. Cortex-M4 supports the Thumb instruction set only, therefore, it generates a fault when trying to jump to an even address. In order to let the assembler generate correct address values, the `.thumb_func` should precede *each* label that identified a branch target.

See https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html

Comment: Has the bin file changed? Are there non-zeroes in the first two words now?

Comment: Good. We are making progress. Now I guess it is faulting somewhere else? You may need to align stack pointer, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Oh I see you have fixed this already. Now, see that all pointers are odd except the Reset vector. As it was pointed out, branch addresses should be odd in the Thumb mode. I have no idea how to tell this to the compiler. Maybe lift the `.thumb_func` line before the definition of _Reset?

Comment: You probably want to use the `.thumb_func` and `.type` directives before *each* label that is a code address.

Comment: Yeah! Works like a charm! I put .thumb_func before _Reset. Can you explain me why .thumb_func is needed?

Comment: Cool. Explained in the answer.